# Cache invalidation is not working in browser using or app Rest API?

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, browser-cache

```
from django.utils.cache import get_cache_key
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@permission_classes((IsPermittedWithoutAuth,))
@cache_page(60 * 5)
def extra_facility(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        "code.............."
        key = get_cache_key(request)
        if cache.has_key(key):
            cache.delete(key)
        return Response({'status': {'code': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                                    'error': None,
                                    'message': 'Extra facility has been added.'
                                    },
                         'data': None,
                         'id': extra.id})
    if request.method == 'GET':

        facility = ExtraFacility.objects.all()
        if params.get('is_active'):
            facility = facility.filter(is_active=get_boolean(params['is_active']))
        result = paginator.paginate_queryset(facility, request)
        serializer = ExtraFacilitySerializer(result, many=True, context={'request': request})
        # next_page = paginator.get_next_link()
    return Response(serializer.data)
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        "code logic "
        key = get_cache_key(request)
        if cache.has_key(key):
            cache.delete(key)
        return Response({"data": serializer.data, "status": {"code": status.HTTP_200_OK,
                                                             "message": "Extra facility has been updated.",
                                                             "error": None}})
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        "code logic"
        key = get_cache_key(request)
        if cache.has_key(key):
            cache.delete(key)
        return Response({"status": {"code": status.HTTP_200_OK,
                                    "message": "Extra Facility has been deleted",
                                    "error": None}})
```

- This API is used in fronted using Reactjs and android app.
- Caching is working perfectly on GET request.
- Caching invalidation is also working using POSTMAN on POST, PUT, and
  DELETE request.

***But Caching invalidation  is not working on POST, PUT, and
   DELETE request when this API is called in browser using Reacjs and  Caching invalidation is also not working in Android app***

Comment: why do you want to cache these?  all these http request types explicitly change the state of the application, so why cache in the first place?  eg, if a user deletes an item, why do you want that in your cache?

Comment: I want to detete cache of GET request  on POST,  DELETE, PUT REQUEST